# Firefox messing with SVG coordinates

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, coordinates

I have created a system of SVG points rotating around a central axis. It works fine in Chrome, Safari and Opera but for a reason I cannot find FF is not displaying elements correctly.

The points seem to be placed correctly but the circles that represent the orbits are not.
Could this be related to the viewBox attribute in my svg tag ?

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-315 -315 630 630">
```

Here is a jsfiddle to help you see the difference of rendering between browsers:
http://jsfiddle.net/n7y238Lf/2/

Comment: It doesn't work on firefox because you only use `-webkit-` vendor prefixes but not the standard syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Could you be a bit more precise ? I checked the answer you provided and it is about transform-origin. But the circles that aren't placed correctly are not using this property. Or maybe I'm missing something ?

Comment: For your animations, you are only defining `-webkit-`-prefixed animation properties.  They will only work on Chrome, Safari and Opera (all of which use the Webkit engine). You need to also include the standard unprefixed versions of each property (eg. `animation`, `animation-duration`, etc) for FF and IE.

Comment: Yes you're right, I have already fixed that, the jsfiddle is a bit old. But the bug I try to fix is about the orbit circles that are not aligned with the center. The points are rotating arount the good axis, but the orbit circles are not corresponding with them. Here is the updated jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lggcwepk/